# Problems with relationships @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have 2 entities (SubModelo and Opcional). The SubModelo may have a list of Opcionals, so a one-way relationship. When I try to persist the SubModelo entity and it has no Opcional on the opcional list, Hibernate persists normally, but if I include some opcional on the list it does not persist and gives me error stating that the opcional entity is not likely to persist.
Hibernate creates a third table for the relationship, but does not include anything.

```
@Entity 
public class SubModelo implements Serializable { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column 
    @Size(max = 30) 
    private String nome; 
    @NotNull 
    @Size (max = 9) 
    private String motor; 
    @NotNull 
    private boolean automatico;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Opcional> opcionais;
```

```
    22:49:56,633 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-10)         WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component SubModeloService for method     public br.com.ozelo.entidades.SubModelo br.com.ozelo.servico.SubModeloService.novoSubModelo(br.com.ozelo.entidades.SubModelo): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: br.com.ozelo.entidades.Opcional
at     org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
at      org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
at      org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
     Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: br.com.ozelo.entidades.Opcional
     at      org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1152)
     at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:580)
    at br.com.ozelo.DAO.BasicDao.addEntity(BasicDao.java:22)
    at br.com.ozelo.DAO.SubModeloDao.novoSubModelo(SubModeloDao.java:24)
     at br.com.ozelo.servico.SubModeloService.novoSubModelo(SubModeloService.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
23:31:01,042 INFO [stdout] (default task-1) javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: br.com.ozelo.entidades.Opcional
```

Comment: try using CascadeType.MERGE - although it is not the proper fix, can you post the code that is actually persisting the entities.

Comment: The Opcional entity instance in the opcionais exists in the database already.  You cannot call persist on a detached instance, as you are essentially telling JPA to insert an already existing instance.  Where are these instances coming from?  Try either reading them in, or using merge as suggested above, as this causes them to be attached.  If they are not existing entities, you will need to show the Opcional class and how you are instantiating new ones